# Trying to make the output of my function in Matlab a 1D array, new to programming

Tags: matlab

i am trying to make the output of this function in matlab a 1D array, but its only giving me a single number as output.[enter image description here][image: 1]

Comment: It looks like `ThreePointSmooth` is returning only a single value. Can you provide some info about that function?
Also that `for`-loop is obsolete in the way you are using it.

Comment: Please add your code and output as text.